# How to get my local timezone irrespective of my ini file server time zone

Tags: php, windows, timezone

In my ini file server time zone declared as below

[image]

but my application installed on another timezone eg: 'America/Los_Angeles' time zone.

using **date_default_timezone_get()** i am always getting Europe/London timezone as it's declared in ini file. How to get local timezone(wherever application is installed) here?

Thanks
Krish

Comment: Hi. If the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question, please let me know and I'll re-open it

Comment: hi linked duplicate doesn't answer my question

Comment: That's not enough to go on; how does it not? What timezone are you after if not the server's?

Comment: i am on windows. but in answers i didn't found any info related to windows. can u help me on this related to windows